# Basic insertion sort optimization is making code slower

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I'm teaching a demo on Insertion Sort tomorrow. One important optimization is to add a check to the inner loop that stops it from iterating once you get an item into the right position. So basically, it's going from this:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
            if (array[j] < array[j-1]) {
                int tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j-1];
                array[j-1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && array[j] < array[j-1]; j--) {
            int tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[j-1];
            array[j-1] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

The second version should be more efficient. However, when I benchmark it, I'm actually measuring the performance of the first version as faster. I can't find the bug. Any ideas what's going on?

Here's the code I'm using to benchmark:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] stuff = getRandomArray(50000);
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stuff));

        long started = System.currentTimeMillis();
        insertionSort(stuff);
        long finished = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long totalTime = finished - started;

        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stuff));

        System.out.println("Started: " + started);
        System.out.println("Finished: " + finished);
        System.out.println("Elapsed: " + totalTime);
    }

    public static int[] getRandomArray(int size) {
        int[] array = new int[size];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = r.nextInt(size);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void insertionSort(int[] array) {
        // Implementation goes here
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Changed the number of items in the test array, and commented out the lines to print

Comment: What margin of *slower* are you experiencing? There *is* an extra compare in the second version and your arrays are *not that long*

Comment: Ah, let me edit this. I notice it when getting close to 50000 items

Comment: I'm getting ~1200 ms for the second version and ~1000 for the first, pretty consistently. Not huge, but I'd expect the first to be close to N^2 computes and the latter to be closer to N^2 / 2. The second algorithm should actually have fewer compares, since the compare that's in the if statement of the first algorithm is being moved to the conditional of the for loop in the second. That should cause the loop to stop sooner.

Comment: This is very weird. Using the code you provided, I get around 2400ms for the first version and ~780ms for the second version on OpenJDK 8 ...

Comment: JVM options can affect benchmark result, you may share it if has any specific option.

Comment: The answer provided by @Uli below worked for me! It taught me a bit more about compiler optimizations than I'd usually think about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you have written a so called microbenchmark. Your results are not meaningful because you don't have a warmup phase. This is essential to let the JVM HotSpot compiler perform its runtime optimizations.

Search for "java microbenchmark" to find some tools. An example is http://java-performance.info/jmh/

Just in case your results are meaningful I suppose that in your 2nd example the loop optimization of the HotSpot compiler is not as efficient as it is in your 1st example.

Comment: Thank you! This ended up being the right answer for me.

Comment: Because this is being used as an example in a very introductory class, I'm a little hesitant to bring in special tools. However, I found that if I add a loop to re-run the same test a few times, the latter results are a lot quicker than the earlier. So I'm going to do that in the demo, and it'll give me a good chance to talk about what's going on, and that the latter runs are more meaningful.